# ModuleParseError: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:7)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, sanity

I am making a ecommerce website by following the tutorial, using next js, react js and sanity. The application was running file up until I got the api key in order to connect to sanity. After I put in the key, I started getting the error below, I even clicked on the link and followed the steps, nothing worked, followed something that was mentioned here and it didn't work.
Error:

Failed to compile

```
./seagreen-sheep/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.d.ts
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:7)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> export type Platform = 'browser' | 'node' | 'neutral';
| export type Format = 'iife' | 'cjs' | 'esm';
| export type Loader = 'base64' | 'binary' | 'copy' | 'css' | 'dataurl' | 'default' | 'empty' | 'file' | 'js' | 'json' | 'jsx' | 'text' | 'ts' | 'tsx';
```

This error occurred during the build process and can only be dismissed by fixing the error.

package.json:

```
{
    "name": "ebusinesscard",  
    
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,  
    
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "next dev",
        "build": "next build",  
        
        "start": "next start",  
        
        "lint": "next lint"
    },  
    
    "dependencies": {  
    
        "@sanity/client": "^3.2.0",
        "@sanity/image-url": "^1.0.1",  
        
        "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.25.0",  
        
        "canvas-confetti": "^1.5.1",  
        
        "next": "13.2.4",  
        
        "next-sanity-image": "^3.2.1",  
        
        "react": "18.2.0",
        "react-dom": "18.2.0",
        "react-hot-toast": "^2.2.0",
        "react-icons": "^4.3.1",
        "stripe": "^8.209.0"
    }
}
```

Client.js:
After I had this file is when the error started, before that everything was working.

```
import sanityCli from "@/seagreen-sheep/sanity.cli";
import { SanityClient } from "@sanity/client";
import { ImageUrlBuilder } from "@sanity/image-url";


export const client = SanityClient({
    projectId: 'hdbv0npd',
    dataset: 'production',
    apiVersion: '2023-03-17',
    useCdn: true,
    token: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_TOKEN
});

const builder = ImageUrlBuilder(client);

export const urlFor = (source) => builder.image (source);
```

Comment: which version of nextjs you are using ?